# How to install the drivers only from a download?

Tags: drivers, windows-server-2012, display-driver

I have an Intel Radeon HD 6700 graphics card. Windows Server 2012 was unable to detect this, so it gave me a standard display adapter instead (no dual monitor support, low-res).

I found the download to the drivers here: http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Pages/radeonaiw_win8-64.aspx

With Windows 7 I never had to install anything, it just retrieved the driver for me. So, I was wondering which files I need and how do I manually get the driver installed so I don't have all this junk in my program files directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the installer and extract it using 7-zip or something similar and then find the folder that houses the drivers, I use a Nvidia card and I found the drivers here,

```
C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\285.62\WinVista_Win7\English\Display.Driver
```

By hitting the upgrade driver button you can install just the drivers.

Just look for a folder with a lot of inf files.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the AMD gaming cards, is not by design to support server. The installer will check only for Windows Vista,7,8,8.1 or 10.

However, the binary codes maybe can work with your server, but may not work with other server.

For Windows Server 2012 R2:
- Right click on start menu
- Select Device Manager
- Go to display adapter - microsoft windows basic display adapter
- Update Driver Software

I use AMD Radeon 6000 series integrated with ASUS motherboard, and the driver is located here:
V:\Drivers\VGA\Vista_WIN7

Always use the latest driver, in my case, i have both Vista and Windows 7, so i choosed windows 7.

Comment: hey,it does not make sense, but it WORKS! I tried many many versions, but only this way of installation bypasses MS